# Blackberry app development - license

Tags: blackberry, distribution

I want to know about BlackBerry app distribution. Do I need to get a license from RIM, similar to the apple developer license, to distribute my app?

Comment: I think this is off-topic because its about licensing (the legal part) rather than a programming question as defined in the help pages of this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information you need is available here:
http://us.blackberry.com/developers/appworld/distribution.jsp

Distribute your applications and themes through the BlackBerry App World™ storefront.

**BlackBerry App World: $0 registration and submission fees.**

To submit your app or theme to BlackBerry App World, you’ll first need to create a vendor account. Once your account credentials have been confirmed, you’ll receive an email with instructions on how to begin submitting your apps or themes. When submitting your app, be sure to include the following:

- Application name, description and icon or logo
- Category in which your app should be placed
- License type (free, paid or try and buy)
- Wireless service providers your app will be available to
- Countries where your app should be distributed
- Releases and file bundles
- Screenshots

Comment: Thanks Aziz, this is what i am looking for. Also one more question, is it mandatory that i distribute my app through app world? Is there any other options available for me?

Comment: I think, users can also install apps using the Application Loader. They can also install jad/cod files via OTA (Over The Air). Look for more info [here](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/5580/Distribute_an_application_from_a_web_page_447183_11.jsp) and [here](http://serialio.com/support/SerialMagic/BlackBerry/Java_application_push_deployment.pdf).

Comment: @Jithesh G: the OTA installation works well and is very easy to set up (you just drop the JAD and matching COD file(s) into a folder in your web app, and then just put a hyperlink to the JAD file on one of your pages). Regarding app world: keep in mind that if your app does anything vaguely related to RIM's "core competency" (i.e. email and messaging) it will be rejected. I know, because I've been there - their lawyers are extremely inflexible about this.